# How to resubscribe a subscriber in mobile connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect

We have a use case where we want to house all unsubscribed in Salesforce CRM but not in Marketing Cloud. This works in email sends as I can always send the transactional emails from Marketing Cloud , as I can source the sending data directly from Salesforce CRM based on the optout flag.

However this does not seems to work in Mobile Connect world. Consider below scenario:
1.  I created the STOP key word with a specific ampscript to update the salesforce object
2.  On receiving the text message when someone replies stop, the sms optout field becomes true in CRM, but the subscriber also gets optout in Marketing Cloud
3.  Now I want to optin the subscriber back in SFMC
For the step three I have tried the following but did not work:
1.Create a data extension to house the mobile unsubscribes
2.Create a query activity to query on Data View: SMSSubscriptionLog, https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sms_subscription_log.htm&type=5 
3. Export the data on SFTP
4. Import this into Mobile Connect All Contact list with the status updated to optin and resubscribe to the mobile connect keyword 
5. This automation should run daily at 9 pm (approximate time)

Can you please let me know is there an automated way to resubscribe a subscriber in mobile connect? I was thinking of following approaches:
1.  Try to disable the stop keyword, and may be name it something like 12344567454_djsjsj, so that a customer can not reply to global stop keyword 
2.  Create another normal keyword STOP with the ampscript to update the CRM object, and when someone replies STOP, they do not get opted out from SFMC but directly from Salesforce CRM
Another approach:
1.  In the global STOP keyword, along with Salesforce object ampscript, add one more specific API ampscript which reoptin the subscriber back in SFMC. In this way when the subscriber replies with STOP, it will not get unsubscribed from SFMC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a DE that tracks who is optin/out of MobileConnect, you can use an import activity from Contact Builder to add new contacts. It will subscribe them to a keyword if they are new.

However is they unsubscribe from a keyword and you import them again with the status active, they will be active but unsubscribe from your keyword. Therefore you cannot talk to them. My solution is to use the [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postQueueMO.htm) call to add them to a keyword. Put this API call in a SSJS script and you can automate it.

Comment: Thank you for providing your insights. The call you shared is for sending the text message. Do you have any sample call which just subscribe a Mobile number to a keyword without sending a text message.

Comment: Did you try it? For it was not sending anything but was updating the keyword opt-in status. Try it using postman, it should work and then incorporate it in SSJS. Here the resource is lass confusing: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/using-the-mobileconnect-api.htm

Comment: Hello Jeremy, Thanks for the details. I'm facing the same issue. I've tried to re-subscribe a contact to a Keyword using the API you proposed but it doesn't work. I get the OK status from the API but the contact is still unsubscribed.