# marketing cloud - how to enable user to receive SMS after STOP

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sms

[image]We used the STOP keyword to avoid subscribers to receive SMS.
Please is there any keyword to re-enable this subscriber to receive it?

Thanks

Comment: ou would configure a optin message to a keyword and you can do a queuemo call to thatkeyword

Comment: Please remember when you use QueueMO API, the end user will get a confirmation message(The opt in message that you configured).

Comment: please could you rephrase it and/or share the related documentation

Comment: Do you have an ADD Keyword configured  for your short code? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postQueueMO.htm

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to  [Delete a Custom STOP Keyword in MobileConnect](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_delete_a_custom_stop_keyword.htm&type=5)

1. In the app switcher, hover over your name and Click Setup.
2. Search for MobileConnect
3. Click the short or long code
4. Click Edit next to Account STOP.
5. Click trash can icon next to the STOP keyword to delete.
6. Click Delete to confirm.

Comment: thanks @Anudeep Gopagoni we did not use a custom stop keyword but we used the standard keyword, does it make any difference?

Comment: I just added an image that shows that there is no edit next to Account STOP

Comment: Can you see the solution listed here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/250556/how-to-resubscribe-a-subscriber-in-mobile-connect

Comment: In Marketing Cloud, you can resubscribe someone without them affirmatively opted in. In journey builder, you'd see this option as "Subscribe users to a keyword." In MobileConnect, you can affirm that all users you're about to send to are opted in, and then send. I can't emphasize how much caution should be used here - the point of STOP is to manage subscriptions, so we should beware of use cases that try to work around someone's opt-in status because Trust.